# How to Access Source Code Using Bluehost Wordpress?

Tags: themes, wordpress

I'm trying to edit the source code on a new website.  I'm using Bluehost Wordpress.  The theme is Codeless:Specular.  I am able to find the theme files, but not the pages themselves.
Most places I checked said to go to public_html/wp-content but I cannont find the page files anywhere.  After searching thoroughly, I am doubting if the page files are in File Manager at all.
By default, the pages are editable using Wordpress PageBakery editor.

EDIT:  What I mean by source code:
I have a home page, which includes a flexslider.  I want to see the html for this flexslider and be able to change id's/etc.  After this, I was hoping I could see the entire page, and each of the other pages as php documents where I could freely rearrange anything.

The closest thing I found was Elementor, which shows an almost-html like form of the code.  But I haven't found the part of the page that includes the flex slider.
If it's all stored in a SQL database, I guess having access to change the database would work.

Anyone know how to get the source code in this situation?

Comment: This mat be better off in WordPress.stack exchange.  Are you arare the content if pages in a WordPress system are stored in a (usually mysql) database?

Comment: Also, source code is a very ambiguous term here - the source code for what?  The source for the generated page can be viewed in the browser. The source for WordPress is available online, and you should be able to get the specific source code for your entire site by dumping the database and entire WordPress.

Comment: I didn't know it went into a database.